# how to correct arrows in slick slider?

Tags: html, css, frontend, slick.js

I have 2 slick slider in a page, but when i click the next button the second slider move instead of the first one. At first it was correct and worked well. Here is my jquery codes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tabel-instant-works-section").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rtl: true,
    prevArrow: $('.next'),
    nextArrow: $('.prev'),
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and my html codes

```
<div class="inastant-works">
    <div class="tabel-instant-works-section">
        <div class="content-instant-works">
          <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/1.png" alt="sketches">
        </div>
        <div class="content-instant-works">
          <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/2.png" alt="sketches">
        </div>
        <div class="content-instant-works">
          <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/3.png" alt="sketches">
        </div>
        <div class="content-instant-works">
          <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/4.png" alt="sketches">
        </div>
        <div class="content-instant-works">
          <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/5.png" alt="sketches">
        </div>
        <div class="content-instant-works">
          <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/6.png" alt="sketches">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button aria-label="Previous" class="prev"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>
      <button aria-label="Next" class="next"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try being more specific about which `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` classes to target, as it may be grabbing the `.next` and `.prev` from two areas of the page if they are not specific enough, and then slick is seeing them as navigation for both sliders.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabel-instant-works-section").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    rtl: true,
    prevArrow: $('.inastant-works .next'),
    nextArrow: $('.inastant-works .prev'),
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="inastant-works">
  <div class="tabel-instant-works-section">
    <div class="content-instant-works">
      <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/1.png" alt="sketches">
    </div>
    <div class="content-instant-works">
      <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/2.png" alt="sketches">
    </div>
    <div class="content-instant-works">
      <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/3.png" alt="sketches">
    </div>
    <div class="content-instant-works">
      <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/4.png" alt="sketches">
    </div>
    <div class="content-instant-works">
      <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/5.png" alt="sketches">
    </div>
    <div class="content-instant-works">
      <img class="tbl-item-img" src="image/drawing/6.png" alt="sketches">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button aria-label="Previous" class="prev"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>
  <button aria-label="Next" class="next"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</div>
```